# Playframework Greenscript error: The type Configurator is already defined

Tags: playframework, greenscript

So I installed the greenscript-1.2.6k module for my Play 1.2.3 server according to the documentation.
When I startup the server and hit one of the pages this is the error I get:

> The file
>   {module:greenscript-1.2.6k}/app/controllers/greenscript/Configurator.java
>   could not be compiled. Error raised is : The type Configurator is
>   already defined

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the greenscript module both installed and as a dependency which caused them to be compiled twice.

Comment: Thanks, i had the same problem.
Go in application.conf and search for the line :
module.greenscript=${play.path}/modules/greenscript-1.2.8b
Comment/remove it and you're good !